# How do I remap the keys to snap windows to the left or right

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

Currently the hotkey is ctr-super-left/right. But I want it to just be super-left/right, is there a setting that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CompizConfig Setting Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/) for this (Download it using Apt if not installed).

Then under *Categories* you will find the *Windows Management button*. Here, click on *Grid*, and under the *Bindings* tab you want to modify the *Left Maximize* and *Right maximize* bindings. Click on the button and simply disable the need for *ctrl* from the binding.